# FPGA - What is the maximum allowed DRAM capacity on an XUPV5-LX110T Development Board?

Tags: fpga, xilinx, dram

I have purchased an XUPV5LX110T FPGA Development board and am unclear as to the size of the DRAM that can be upgraded.

Currently I have a SODIMM 256MB that I am looking to increase for the possibility of using a good portion as Frame Buffering memory for a GPU Project I am undertaking.

If expandable, what compatible chips can be used as a substitute to the default DRAM that is provided with the board?

Comment: Ask the board manufacturer!

Comment: On the ML506/7 when I was using them a few years ago, the practical limit was 1GB because I couldn't find larger SODIMMs at the time. As DDR2 is now trailing edge, you probably still can't, but I haven't looked recently.

Comment: The best I just found was 4GB SODIMM - Micron 4GB DDR2 667Mhz CL5 PC2-5300 200Pin CL5 Laptop Memory For Micron (MT16HTS51264HY-667A1)

Answer (score 2):

As long as all the required pins are connected, you should be able to put in the largest RAM that the memory controller on the FPGA will support. Which is probably the biggest module in that form factor.

Comment: According to ML505/ML506/ML507 
Evaluation Platform
www.xilinx.com
Page 19
UG347 (v3.1.2) May 16, 2011
Detailed Description
R
DDR2 Memory Expansion
The DDR2 interface support user installation of SODIMM modules with more memory 
since higher order address and chip select signals are also routed from the SODIMM to the FPGA.

https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/boards_and_kits/ug347.pdf